# Searchkick index blob columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I'm trying to use Searchkick gem to provide full text search for a blob column in MySQL database, the column has text data stored in binary format, will become readable when using `Zlib.inflate(model_column)` function.

Is there is a way to perform data conversion before passing it to searchkick?

Adding searchkick to other models in my application works, only when indexing blob column, I get this error

```
 Events.first.reindex
  Events Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` LIMIT 1
  Events Store (3.4ms)  {"id":"","exception":["Encoding::UndefinedConversionError","\"\\x9C\" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"]}
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x9C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could control what data is indexed with the `search_data` method. Call `Model.reindex` after changing this method. For example:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def search_data
    {
      blob: Zlib.inflate(model_column)
      # ...
    }
  end
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing